# Changing Theme of Suggestion drop down container

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

How do you change the text colors and background colors in the google places suggestion drop down container? My app allows a user to change theme, and I was able to successfully change the tint color of the bar, but my results are always white. Is there a way I can change that?

Comment: I take it that you mean the suggestion drop down container?

Comment: I was able to do what I wanted with this http://sweettutos.com/2015/09/30/how-to-use-the-google-places-autocomplete-api-with-google-maps-sdk-on-ios/